# linux bash - Parse date in custom format

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, date

I have a date in a the `%c` format *(could be any other)* and I need to use it in the date command. `%c` is NOT the American format. It is the German one because it's a German server. This also did not work properly on an American server. (Locales set to German or American)

This does not work (error included):

```
user@server:~$ NOW=$(date +%c); echo $NOW
Do 19 Dez 2013 22:33:28 CET
user@server:~$ date --date="$NOW" +%d/%m/%Y
date: ungültiges Datum „Do 19 Dez 2013 22:33:28 CET“
```

*(date: ungültiges Datum „Do 19 Dez 2013 22:33:28 CET“ = `date: invalid date „Do 19 Dez 2013 22:33:28 CET“`)*

The difficulty is that I don't know which locale or even whci dateformat will be used later since the user can set their own format. So a simple specific parsing solution ist not really going to work!

But how do I do it?

To gerneralize the issue:

If I have a date format `format1` *(which could be any or at least one that can be reversed)* I can use date to get a formatted date. But if I want to format it to another date (`format2`) how do I do it?
Any solution using anything else than the coreutils is pointless since I am trying to develop a bash script for as many unix machines as possible.

```
DATE=$(date "+$format1")

date --date="$DATE" "+$format2" # Error in most cases!
```

This is needed because I have a command which the user can give a date format. This date string is going to be displayed. But in a later step I need to convert this date string into another fixed one. I can manipulate the whcih format the command will get and I can maniplulate the output *(or what the user will see)*.
I cannot run the command twice because it is very time consuming.

---

### Update:

I have found something like a solution:

```
# Modify $user_format so it can be parsed later
user_format="$user_format %s"

# Time consuming command which will print a date in the given format
output=$(time_consuming_command params "$user_format" more params)

# This will only display what $user_format used to be
echo ${output% *}

# A simple unix timestamp parsing ("${output##* }" will only return the timestamp)
new_formated_date=$(date -d "1970-01-01 ${output##* } sec UTC" "+$new_format")
```

This is working and might be helpful to others. So I will share this with you.

Comment: Why does that not work?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Hmmm, can we please see the output of your `date +%c`?

Comment: what's the output of `env | grep ^LC`

Comment: What is the point of getting the current date using format1 and then using it to print in format2? Can't you go straight to get the current date in fomrat2? If you are trying this on a non-current date, say a date extracted from a file or table, then it will make more sense.

Comment: Could you better explain the specific use case? I don't think you can use this kind of generic approach, especially with just bash and coreutils.. (there are libraries that try to guess the datetime format, but of course they aren't either perfect nor in any standard library..)

Comment: @alvits I read it out of a long time consuming command which will not return the current date. In my question I just used a simple to reproduce pseudo problem.

Comment: @BrainStone Ok, if you have the chance to do so, using unix timestamps would definitely be the right way :) BTW, you can use: date -d "@${timestamp}", instead of the 1970-01-01 hack (although I'm not 100% sure about the timezone support.. but you should be able to customize that by setting the ``TZ`` variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you store the time as unixtime (ie milliseconds since 1st of january 1970) Like `1388198714`?

The requested exercise in trying to parse all date formats from all around the world as a one shot bash script without reasonable dependecies is slightly ridiculous.

Comment: I agree. As OP stated: "I don't know which locale or even whci dateformat will be used later since the user can set their own format." Imagine what happens with numeric months (US: 12/9/2013, DE: 9.12.2013). Misinterpretation guaranteed! Avoid at all cost using user-configured output as input for additional scripting.

Comment: I suggested something like this in my question. I think something like this would be the best solution.

Answer (score 10):

Not possible with `--date` as of GNU coreutils 8.22. From the date manual:

> ‘-d datestr’
>
> ‘--date=datestr’
>
> Display the date and time specified in datestr instead of the current
>   date and time. datestr can be in almost any common format. It can
>   contain month names, time zones, ‘am’ and ‘pm’, ‘yesterday’, etc. For
>   example, --date="2004-02-27 14:19:13.489392193 +0530" specifies the
>   instant of time that is 489,392,193 nanoseconds after February 27,
>   2004 at 2:19:13 PM in a time zone that is 5 hours and 30 minutes east
>   of UTC.
>
> Note: input currently must be in locale independent format. E.g., the
>   LC_TIME=C below is needed to print back the correct date in many
>   locales:
>
> ```
> date -d "$(LC_TIME=C date)"
> ```

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Options-for-date.html#Options-for-date

Note it says that the input format cannot be in a locale-specific format.

There may be other libraries or programs that would recognize more date formats, but for a given date format it would not be difficult to write a short program to convert it to something date recognizes (for example, with Perl or awk).

Comment: Thank youn for your information but this solution is not going to help me. I don't know for sure which date format it will be so I cannot use a specific parsing method.

Comment: Thank you! My locale (`"en_GB.UTF-8"`) had been causing trouble. The prefix `LC_TIME=C` fixed it! Curiously, the text in my system's man page is much shorter (Manjaro, coreutils 8.30-1)

Answer (score 2):

You may use `libdatetime-format-flexible-perl`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DateTime::Format::Flexible;
my $date_str = "So 22 Dez 2013 07:29:35 CET";
$parser = DateTime::Format::Flexible->new;
my $date = $parser->parse_datetime($date_str);
print $date
```

Default output will be `2013-12-22T07:29:35`, but since `$date` is not a regular string but object, you can do something like this:

```
printf '%02d.%02d.%d', $date->day, $date->month, $date->year;
```

<s>Also `date` behavior probably should be considered as a bug. I think so, because date in the same format but in russian is parsed correctly.</s>

```
$ export LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
$ NOW="$(date "+%c")"
$ date --date="$NOW" '+%d.%m.%Y'
22.12.2013
```

Comment: Well. As @Gavin Smith said, I was wrong about GNU Date — this behavior should not be considered as a bug. Especially because russian date is **not** parsed correctly. It does not fail, yes. But recognize any date as current date: 
`$ date --date="Вск 1 Дек 2013 06:09:16"` will produce
`Вск Дек 22 00:00:00 MSK 2013`

Comment: I have two questions: 1. Is this always installed? 2. Does this work with every date format?

Comment: @BrainStone 1. Of course `libdatetime-format-flexible-perl` is not always installed — even Perl at all is not always installed by default. But it’s still more portable than `date --date` (which is GNU extension) because available not only on GNU but also on FreeBSD, OS X, etc.

Comment: @BrainStone 2. It pretends to be able parse any unambiguous format. But surely, you can invent one which will be readable by human but not by this module. E. g. it fails to parse string where time is ahead of date: `12:00 01 März 2013` (I do not know any tool uses this format though). And obviously, it is not able to distinguish between `10/12/2013` as `12 Oct` and `10/12/2013` as `10 Dec`. The first one (american-style) is default, but you may overwrite it with `european => 1` option.

Comment: @DimitryAlexandrov then it does not fit my needs. I need this to work on almost any GNU system. The script I am writing is for these systems and I cannot assume that anything but the default tools are installed... But still a noteable solution.

Comment: @BrainStone If you can not install additional packages, there is a very little hope of finding any solution. However, if we assume that Perl is already installed (it’s most probably true), you can install Perl modules to userspace along with your script.

Comment: @DimitryAlexandrov I would really like to avoid installing anything.

Comment: @BrainStone But you can’t avoid installing your own script, can you?

Comment: @DimitryAlexandrov It's just a little bash script. Nothing more. Uploading and done. And the user knows if they are going to install it or not. But if my script installs something it might be considered a virus. This simply is not a suitable solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant the formatting is wrong, I *think* what you want is:

```
NOW=$(date +%c)
date --date="$NOW" +%d/%m/%Y
```

note the lowercase `%d` and `%m`.

Locally, this is what I get:

```
root@server2:~# NOW=$(date +%c)
root@server2:~# date --date="$NOW" +%d/%m/%Y
19/12/2013
```

Comment: It is not parsing. I do not care about the output date format the input date format is the important one!