# What are valid input DATE formats for the (Linux) date command?

Tags: linux, bash, date, scripting

The following command generates the date for the next day:

```
date -d "20150615 12:00 +1 day" +%Y%m%d
20150616
```

I would like to specify my own INPUT date format, such as:

2015_06_15

But the date command does not like this format and complains about invalid date:

```
date: invalid date '2015_06_15 12:00 +1 day'
```

Is it possible to use such a date format? And if so how could I do this.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691852/linux-bash-parse-date-in-custom-format - the date command does not have an input format specifier, you would have to convert the input into something date understands by default.

Comment: GNU `date` does not allow you to specify an input format; the full documentation for what *is* accepted can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats).

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if a proposal can be floated to add such a feature to GNU date ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround:

```
x="2015_06_15"
date -d "${x//_/} 12:00 +1 day" +%Y%m%d
```

Output:

```
20150616
```

Comment: For others wondering like myself what x//_/ means this is called expansion found in zsh manual 14.3 Parameter Expansion:  
ex.1${name/pattern/repl} 
ex.2 ${name//pattern/repl} - replace all occurances of pattern "_" with "" so it truncates the input date to 20150615 which is a readable format.  
ex.3${name:/pattern/repl}