# Interpreting date strings with correct locale (Bash, date)

Tags: linux, bash, date, locale

I wish to read in a date string from user input and convert it to a consistent format within a bash script. I am having difficulty working with international Locales, since the date command is defaulting to US-date format (mm/dd/yyyy) and I am in Britain, so my users are more likely to use dd-mm-yyyy.  But, I don't wish to limit their input method, so if the user inputs yyyy-mm-dd, dd-mmm-yyyy, etc, I still want to work with their inputs and correctly interpret them.

So far, I have found this syntax which is close:
`date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d %DATETOCHECK`

Sample inputs --> outputs:

```
31-Dec-2017  --> 2017-12-31 [OK]
2017-12-31   --> 2017-12-31 [OK]
31/12/2017   --> Fails with return code 1
```

I'd like to make use of the date command if possible, because this already has an immense amount of flexibility.

Question: How can I make it so that it always assumes that dd/mm/yyyy is never mm/dd/yyyy?

(I have tried adding 'export LC_ALL=en_GB' at the start of my script, but this has not made any difference. Maybe I'm not applying this right, or the Locale is not set up how I would expect).

Using Suse Linux Enterprise Desktop 10,
`Linux DCTL7132-13 2.6.16.21-0.8-smp #1 SMP Mon Jul 3 18:25:39 UTC 2006 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Update: This has been flagged as a duplicate of another question. I agree that I am asking the same question, but I cannot identify a suitable answer in the responses given to that question ([linux bash - Parse date in custom format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691852/linux-bash-parse-date-in-custom-format)).

Further, in that article, a common syntax is:

```
NOW=$(date +%c); echo $NOW
```

When I run this, I get response 'Illegal variable name.' (Ah, that is because my shell was tcsh; when I change it to bash, the command works from command line)

Regards,
Nigel

Comment: OK, I'm giving up.  Here's my hack of a solution.

Comment: OK, I'm giving up.  Here's my hack of a solution.

`function InStr() {
  x="${1%%$2*}"
  [[ "$x" = "$1" ]] && echo -1 || echo "$((1+${#x}))"
}`

`function CnvDt() {
  MD=`date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d $1 2>&1`
  RES=$?
  [[ $RES -eq 0 ]] echo "$MD" : echo -1
}`

`read -p "Input date: " USRIP
SP1=$(InStr "$USRIP" "/")
if [[ $SP1 -ne -1 ]]; then  
  MIDSTR=${USRIP:SP1}
  SP2=$(($SP1 + $(InStr "$MIDSTR" "/")))
  MLN=$(($SP2 - $SP1))
  YLN=$((${#USRIP} - $SP2))  
  # Swap mm and dd parts
  USRIP=${USRIP:SP1:MLN}${USRIP:0:SP1}${USRIP:SPS2:YLN}
fi

CnvDte $USRIP`